# TextBox Values not updating on click command

Tags: vb.net

Im experimenting with upgrading from VBA to VB.NET, so I am learning some pretty basic stuff by figuring out the syntax differences between things I have done and). So far so good, but I cant seem to get a textbox to update the display value in the form. Anyone want to explain why I am dumb? I spent some time surfing the various interweb stuff, but have yet to find anything(unless I am dumb and just didnt understand it when i saw it).

Here's what I have so far:

```
    Dim this As String = Trim$(Mid$(TextBox1.Text, InStr(TextBox1.Text, "&") + 1))
    Dim oldtxt As String = TextBox1.Text
    If InStr(TextBox1.Text, "&") > 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(TextBox1.Text, "End Date Copied" & this)
        Clipboard.SetText(this)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(TextBox1.Text, oldtxt)
    End If
```

Comment: Have you debugged? Set a breakpoint at the top of the code and step through it line by line, examining the state at each step to see whether it matches what you expect.

Comment: That said, setting the `Text` twice in the one event handler with a `Thread.Sleep` in between is just not on.  If you want to display one set of text and then another after a delay then set the first text only in that event handler and then start a `Timer`.  You can then set the second text in the `Tick` event handler of that `Timer`.

Comment: You mention a "Click command" in your title, yet you are using an `Enter` event for a `TextBox`. Do you want this text to update when a button is clicked, or when a user enters the `TextBox` (in this instance, a `TextBox` called `TextBox1`)?

Comment: sorry click. i might have typed the wrong thing. Click/enter same thing me thinks (not technically but anecdotally)

Comment: Note you should use the `.Trim` and `.SubString` extension methods of a String rather than `Trim$` and `Mid$`

Comment: In .NET, there is a distinct difference. So, to clarify, do you want this to update when a `Button` has been clicked, or when a user enters the `TextBox`. `Enter` in this instance doesn't mean the return key, it means "the user has entered the control". At the moment, this code runs when the user enters the control.

Comment: I know that enter means "when you enter it" and for the above scenario they difference between click and enter is irrelevant. I did not realize that .substring was a better idea though. Still doesnt really address the issue but if its a good bext practice approach thats good to know

Comment: We don't know it's irrelevant because you mixed up your terminology! If you're asking for help, you need to be as precise as possible.

Comment: Either entering or clicking should result in the same effect? I tried do this with both Enter and Click events and the Clipboard copy part works but the resetting of text does not work. So yes, for changing text display  either click or enter should be sufficient. The fact that i mixed terminology is actually irrelevant for the end result here. If you're splitting hairs pointlessly then youre just wasting both of our times

Comment: Maybe try changing this line `TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(TextBox1.Text, oldtxt)` to just simply `TextBox1.Text = oldtxt`

Comment: @jmcilhinney is that your codebank thread from vbForums.com?  If so youre awesome! I am learning quite a bit

Comment: I'm not sure which thread you mean specifically but I have posted a number there so it probably is mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the UI of visual studio I was able to find a more "band-aid" type of resolution. Even though I havent messed with SubString function yet, that is my next learning step, I found this option to be sufficient in the immediate resolution. If I find a better way of implementing this I will post back for others to see (if they care).

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Block1.Enter
 Dim this As String = Trim$(Mid$(TextBox1.Text, InStr(TextBox1.Text, "&") + 1))
 Dim oldtxt As String = TextBox1.Text
 If InStr(TextBox1.Text, "&") > 0 Then 
      TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(TextBox1.Text, "End Date Copied" & this)
      Block1.Refresh()
      Clipboard.SetText(this)
      Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
      TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(TextBox1.Text, oldtxt)
      Block1.Refresh()
 End If
 End Sub
```

And just an FYI for @TEK, Enter and Click events for this work identically, so hopefully next time you try and help someone you wont get hung up on unnecessary details :)

Comment: `TextBox Values not updating on click command` and your code was using the *Enter* event?  TEK was making very relevant remarks.  You are the one that *needs* to get hung up on *necessary* details.  You will get better help.

Comment: Well seeing in how the event handler had nothing to do with what the execution of the code was actually trying to do, no he wasnt. Literally the event handler could have been pretty much anything else, and the end result would  be the same. I could have left out that part entirely and would've had the same issue. So no it wasn't relevant and literally had nothing to do with what my question was actually referencing. thanks though.

Comment: Why are you using Replace at all in this code?  It's not really needed.  Just use `TextBox1.Text = "End Date Copied" & this` and later `TextBox1.Text = oldtxt`  It would make the code much easier to read.

Comment: Good point. I tried this before i discovered the Refresh() clause and it didnt work. But it looks like it should work fine afterwards. Thanks for pointing that out.